# Returning data from ckeditor with mulitple instances

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I've got several ckeditor instances on the same page which each is submitting a different form however the data is not being submitted.  I've tried getting the ckeditor instance using other methods but I am unable to get the correct instance, it's always giving me the first one so I'm unable to grab the data.  The documentation says that with jquery ckeditor should automatically return the correct data, however it is not.  What am I missing here?

```
$('.newmail').submit(function(event) { 
            var CKEDITOR   = window.parent.CKEDITOR;   
    for ( var i in CKEDITOR.instances ){
       var currentInstance = i;
       break;
    }

    var oEditor   = CKEDITOR.instances[currentInstance].getData();

            alert(oEditor);

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: $(this).processJson
    }); 

    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your form working properly even without ckeditor? It looks like the html code is not well organized; make sure your  tags are closed in the right way

Comment: I'm the one who asked this question but did so w/out an account. @Mauro, I'm not sure how my html code is relevant giving I didn't include any in the example. The code does work correctly on all fronts, I just do not receive the data from ckeditor to php.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you use jQuery, perhaps it would be better if you implemented ckEditor with the help of its jquery adapter? You can instantiate it by doing the following:

```
$("#id_of_textarea").ckeditor();
```

Then you can do the following for each editor instance before you submit your form:

```
$("textarea#id_of_textarea").val($("#id_of_textarea.editor").val());
```

That way, the value that has been entered into the editor will be set as the textarea value, and the submit will catch it.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense.  I had a misunderstanding of the jquery adapter, thinking that simply including the file was all that was needed.  Thanks for your help.